# How can i write correct oracle connection string in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm beginner in oracle and c# ,i want simple application in c# use the oracle database,i write this connection string for connect to the database:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BEHBEHZAD;User ID=SYSTEM;Password=beh1368421";
```

my full code is this:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BEHBEHZAD;User ID=SYSTEM;Password=beh1368421";

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Connect Successfull!!");
            }
            catch (Exception )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Disconnect!!");

            }
```

but when i run that program i get Disconnect Message,my TNS file detail is this:

```
BEHBEHZAD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = behbehzad)
    )
  )
```

How can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: It depends on which component you're using in order to connect. Assuming you're using Oracle Data Provider for .NET, your string is correct. Try putting your full TNS (without its name) in the connection string.

Comment: Try to write "User Id" instead of "User ID".

Comment: @NeriaNachum i put that,but get not valid connection string

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in the second comment as well?

Comment: Ohh no,please wait my friend. @NeriaNachum

Comment: @NeriaNachum i change my connection string to this:conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BEHBEHZAD;User Id=SYSTEM;Password=beh1368421"; but so get error

Comment: Can you please post the thrown exception?

Comment: @NeriaNachum i get this exception :{"ORA-12557: TNS:protocol adapter not loadable"}

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12557 is apparently not related to your connection string but to a problem with your Path variable. Please follow the instructions in [this article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12577.htm).

Comment: i change path variable to this:C:\app\BEHZAD-HUSH\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN but so get error!

Comment: Another issue that I read about - make sure that your Oracle client and your compiled application are both in x86 or in x64. I faced a lot of issues due to this discrepancy.

Comment: My application just run x64 mode

Comment: @No my friend on x64 get ORA error in connection string,but on x86 get Token error dll.